# How to use a String instead of &str in iterator, if/else block

Tags: rust

Would someone be kind enough to explain to me why using a `String` in this script does not work but `&str` does. Additionally how can I modify it so that it will work with `String`'s? [version 1.2]

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap};

fn main() { 

    let mut hash = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    hash.insert("this", "value");
    let l: &str = "this is a borrowed string reference";
    // If the above line was defined as:
    //let l: String = "this is a string".to_string();

    let mut all = l.split(" ");   
    let name: &str = all.next().unwrap();

    if hash.contains_key(name) == true {
        hash.remove(name);
    } else {
        hash.insert(name, "stuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` *where*?  There's four different places `&str` could be replaced with `String`, all with different reasons why it may or may not work.  Do you mean *just* changing the type of `l`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let's boil this down to just the necessities:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() { 
    let mut hash = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    hash.insert("this", "value");
    let l: String = "this is a borrowed string reference".to_string();
    hash.insert(&l, "stuff");
}
```

Compiling this gives us:

```
<anon>:7:18: 7:19 error: `l` does not live long enough
<anon>:7     hash.insert(&l, "stuff");
                          ^
<anon>:4:49: 8:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 4:48...
<anon>:4     let mut hash = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
<anon>:5     hash.insert("this", "value");
<anon>:6     let l: String = "this is a borrowed string reference".to_string();
<anon>:7     hash.insert(&l, "stuff");
<anon>:8 }
<anon>:6:71: 8:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 6:70
<anon>:6     let l: String = "this is a borrowed string reference".to_string();
<anon>:7     hash.insert(&l, "stuff");
<anon>:8 }
```

Which tells you more or less *exactly* what it won't work.  You try to insert a borrowed pointer to the `String` `l` into the hashmap.  However, the `String` simply doesn't live long enough.

Specifically, values are destroyed by Rust in reverse lexical order.  So, when execution gets to the end of the function, Rust will deallocate `l` *first*, followed by `hash`.  This is a problem: it means that there is a window during which `hash` contains pointers to destroyed data, which Rust absolutely *will not allow*.

The reason this works with a `&str` is that a string literal `"like this"` is not merely `&str`; it's actually `&'static str`.  This means that a string literal "lives" for the entire duration of the program: it *never* gets destroyed, thus it's safe for the hashmap to hold a pointer to it.

The solution is to ensure the `String` will outlive the `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() { 
    // Declare `l` here ...
    let l;
    let mut hash = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    hash.insert("this", "value");

    // ... but initialise it *here*.
    l = "this is a borrowed string reference".to_string();
    hash.insert(&l, "stuff");
}
```

Now, `hash` gets destroyed *first*, followed by `l`.  It's fine to leave a variable uninitialised, so long as you *do* initialise it prior to reading or using it.

Comment: Thanks I was really stumped there for a while, that makes it very clear!

Comment: "values are destroyed by Rust in reverse lexical order" – Umm no, they're destroyed in reverse order of _declaration_: http://is.gd/LEBmOi

Comment: "lexical" as in the order they appear lexically; *i.e.* in the text.

Answer (score 2):

If you change `l` to `String` you get:

> error: `l` does not live long enough

Which is true:

`name` is a reference to one of the substrings of `l`. You're possibly inserting the `name` reference to `hash`, but the lifetime of `hash` is longer than the lifetime of `l`. Therefore when the lifetime of `l` ends, `hash` would contain invalid references. This is not allowed. F.ex. if you remove the `insert` line, Rust is happy.

There are multiple ways to fix it, depending on your needs. One of them would be to make the lifetime of `hash` shorter than the lifetime of `l`, by instantiating `hash` after `l`:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap};

fn main() { 
    // let l: &str = "this is a borrowed string reference";
    // If the above line was defined as:
    let l: String = "this is a string".to_string();

    let mut hash = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    hash.insert("this", "value");

    let mut all = l.split(" ");   
    let name: &str = all.next().unwrap();

    if hash.contains_key(name) == true {
        hash.remove(name);
    } else {
        hash.insert(name, "stuff");
    }
}
```

Or, you could store copies of the strings in the map.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lifetime issue.

Any object inserted into `hash` must only reference things that outlive `hash` (or not reference anything at all).

However, here, you define `l` after `hash` and therefore `l` has a shorter lifetime. In turn this means that `name` which references `l`'s buffer has a shorter lifetime than `hash` and thus `name` is not suitable to be inserted into `hash` (though it can be used to search/remove).

Switching the order in which `l` and `hash` are defined make it work:

```
use std::collections::{HashMap};

fn main() { 
    let l: String = "this is a string".to_string();

    let mut hash = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();
    hash.insert("this", "value");

    let mut all = l.split(" ");   
    let name: &str = all.next().unwrap();

    if hash.contains_key(name) == true {
        hash.remove(name);
    } else {
        hash.insert(name, "stuff");
    }
}
```

If this is not possible, then use a `HashMap<String, String>` to avoid lifetime issues.